# Kivy .kv file global variables puzzle

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I declared some color constants as global variables in .kv file. They work in certain situations but not in others. An example `ColorConstants.kv` is

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

#:set BLUE (0, 0, 1, 1)
#:set WHITE (1, 1, 1, 1)

<Header@BoxLayout>:
    # color constants don't work here: NoneType errors
    # font_color: WHITE
    # header_color: BLUE
    # need to use numeric lists for font_color, header_color
    font_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
    header_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
    header_text: ""
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(50)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.header_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Label:
        color: root.font_color
        text: root.header_text
        bold: True

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Header:
        header_text: "My Header"
    Label:
        # color constants work here, no errors
        color: BLUE
        text: "This is blue text on white"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: WHITE
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

Accompanying `ColorConstants.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App

class ColorConstantsApp(App):
    pass

ColorConstantsApp().run()
```

I am confused why I can use `BLUE` and `WHITE` in `Label` but not in `Header`. If I use `WHITE` and `BLUE` for `font_color` and `header_color` instead of the `(1,1,1,1)` and `(0,0,1,1)`, I encounter a  `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the canvas instructions are being created before the `header_color` is assigned. You can work around that by changing:

```
        rgba: self.header_color
```

to:

```
        rgba: self.header_color if self.header_color else (0,1,0,1)
```

This just checks if `header_color` is `None` and uses something else in that case. Then, when `header_color` is assigned, the correct color is used.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I do not think that "the canvas instructions are being created before `header_color` is assigned" is correct.
This is because when `header_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)` is used, it works. So this means `header_color` is processed before canvas instructions.
Only when `header_color: BLUE` is used, the bug appears. However, `BLUE` is defined as the `Label` below works correctly (after using `header_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)`.
So there is something else going on beneath the hood.